# Download the first 75 pages in an RSS feed to python

Tags: python, rss, urllib2

Given the URL of a page's RSS XML for example **http://feeds.abcnews.com/abcnews/topstories**

How can I download the HTML for each of the latest 75 pages in the RSS feed using `python` and `urllib2`?

Or is there an easier way to access the sites of RSS feeds such as another python module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you could take a look at [feedparser](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/feedparser).

Also, check out this [introductory usage information](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/feedparser/using-feedparser-in-python).